# Drupal 6 and YUI Editor 2.8, cannot get upload image working

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, yui, wysiwyg, yui-editor

Okay, I have installed WYSIWYG module to my Drupal 6 site. I also installed the YUI module v2.8.0r4

I cannot get the image upload to work. When you click image, you get the option to insert URL etc, but no upload form.

I searched and searched for days trying to find the issue but nothing seems to work. I have seen this issue with many others as well.

Has anybody had this problem? Or can anybody help me out with it? It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMCE Wysiwyg Bridge only works with the TinyMCE and FCKEditor thus the YUI editor with the Wysiwyg module does no allow image importing with YUI.

However the YUI and YUI_Editor modules do allow uploading with IMCE (checkbox from YUI Edit profile configuration screen):

> Allow users to browse images directly from the editor for insertion into the editor. Note: IMCE module must be installed and configured for this to work. Works only with YUI 2.5.x at present.

So it looks like you can get the http://drupal.org/project/yui and http://drupal.org/project/yui_editor modules to do what you want (with IMCE).

Hopefully this helps and good luck!

Comment: Ugh! That worked. I dont know how I missed that. Thats how it was set up in the first place, then I changed to WYSIWYG to see if that could fix it. Thanks heaps for that. Saved me!

Comment: ohh now it is uploading and showing the image in the editor, but when viewing the page is disappears (even from the source code). Then going back into edit mode, it shows up again.. any idea why that would be?

Comment: Silly question, but are you using the Filtered HTML input type? Other things to look out for would be a permission.

Comment: Not so silly, because that was the answer. HTML Filter was set to On. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

What plugin did you use for wysiwyg?
If i remember, tinymce or fckeditor plugins can work with imce + imce_wysiwyg modules. Attach imce button in buttons checkboxes, you'll see in image insert form Browse button, where imce show to you form of uploading.

Comment: I believe it is WYSIWYG v2 (http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg)

I have installed and tested IMCE with the IMCE/WYSIWYG bridge and the same issue applied. So I dumped that without too much investigation, since I prefer the YUI editor. I really just cannot figure it out, it gets so frustrating you know?